# Applying a function to a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

```
res_log <- lapply(res, log2)
```

`res` is a `list` and each element is a `MATRIX`. I get the error.

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : '1' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Comment: Both commands work on my machine. I used the follwoing matrix: `res <- matrix(1:9, 3)`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `lapply(res, 1, log2)`? That would give you the exact error message you describe

Comment: @SvenHohenstein : for me it gives -> **apply(res, 1, log2) : dim(X) must have a positive length**

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the matrix you're using, NOT your use of `apply`. Post information about your matrix if you'd like help.

Comment: What is the result of `str(res)`?

Comment: Thread is closed. See the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to calculate the base-2 logarithm of all values of the matrices in the list `res`, you can use the following command:

```
lapply(res, log2)
```

The command `apply(res, 1, log2)` will not work since a list has no rows. This can only be used with a single matrix object (or an array).

An example:

```
res <- rep(list(matrix(1:9, 3)), 2)

# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
# 
# [[2]]
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9


lapply(res, log2)

# [[1]]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.000000 2.000000 2.807355
# [2,] 1.000000 2.321928 3.000000
# [3,] 1.584963 2.584963 3.169925
# 
# [[2]]
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 0.000000 2.000000 2.807355
# [2,] 1.000000 2.321928 3.000000
# [3,] 1.584963 2.584963 3.169925
```